# Maldives-PLANTATION - VEGETABLES AND FLOWER

Tags: vegetables, flowers

I am living in Maldives, this country is full of islands. all over surrounded by ocean. Climate- mostly summer and sometimes rainy ( April to July- occasional raining). Sandy land.

Please help me out- what type of vegetables and flowers can I grow in small pots ( both indoor and outdoor) and how?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say small pots ,how small, in terms of depth and width measurement?

Comment: Hi and welcome! This is a big question so if we can narrow it down it would help answer it. Is there anything specific you like, or have seen, and want help knowing whether it will work in a small pot? How much sun or shade do you have where you want these plants? A picture of your yard would be great. Thanks!